# What steps must an employer take to keep health information confidential?

Tags: canada, health, british-columbia, confidentiality

I asked this on [workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/166929/what-steps-must-an-employer-take-to-keep-health-information-confidential/166935#166935) but perhaps it's a better fit here.

With my job we are required to get COVID testing frequently. They normally hire different labs to do the testing so each time there's some administrative differences.

Last time I was asked to fill out a survey that was done through Google Docs/Google forms. The survey contained health information such as my personal health care number, birthday etc. Is it legal for a medical office to put client information on Google Forms? Is it safe and private enough?

Also there was a lineup to check in. The receptionist was behind a thick piece of plastic. She told us to yell so she could hear us. She needed personal health information (simillar to the survey) so when each person in the line was yelling it everyone else could hear it. Is this legal?

If I refused to comply with these, could my employer dismiss me or what would happen? I understand I must get COVID tested to do the job but perhaps a better lab could be contracted.

Comment: In the US this would clearly be a violation of HIPPA. But I don't know what laws on this topic Canada or BC has.